# How important is controlling intonation for creating voice?

Tags: voice, intonation

As far as I understand, rhythm is the pattern of stress and non-stress in the sound of prose, and intonation is the full sound quality of the syllable, including pitch, stress, and duration, but not the phonic sound itself. How important is controlling intonation for creating voice, compared to simply controlling rhythm?

Comment: Intonation is the variation in pitch in spoken language. Of course it is "the phonic sound itself". Written language doesn't have intonation.

Answer (score 0):

While you can suggest intonation in your characterizations through simile -- "Good Morning," he said, sounding like molasses in February. Or by spelling out a character's patios or creole as they literally uttered the words -- see 'Cloud Atlas' or most any of the novels by Mark Twain -- it generally gets in the way of good writing because it gets tedious to read. Some people really really like it, but for most a little goes a long way.  You can tell this because even authors that writing in dialect use it sparingly, for emphasis or for effect in emotional moments.

Comment: 'He drawled out his "Good morning," about as hurriedly as molasses in February.'

Comment: @Jedediah, your’s work great. Mine was only illustrating a point. No point giving away my A material for free.